# Multi Collinearity in SEM

Tags: multicollinearity, structural-equation-modeling

in Structural equation modeling, can Collinearity occurred only between multiple independent (exogenous) variables or it can occurred between a latent mediation variable and a latent dependent variable too?

Answer (score 1):

Collinearity is about the correlation between predictors.

If a mediator and outcome are highly correlated, that will change the parameter value of, and increase the standard error of, the indirect effect.

Is that what you mean?